# Extending and customizing existing REST API

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey, jax-rs

I wanted to extend or customize my existing rest apis. In my rest the Service calls the Handler which is supposed to contain business logic (as a product) and I need a way to extend or customize this (per client customization). Please advise how to go about doing this. Attached is a simple hello world setup I have, it would be great it a hook into this 'DefaultGreetingsHandler.greetUser' can be shown.

```
package com.myapi.greetings.rest;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.myapi.greetings.handler.GreetingsHandler;
import com.myapi.greetings.model.Greeting;


@Path("/greetings")
public class GreetingsService {

    @Inject
    GreetingsHandler handler;

    @GET
    @Path("/{name}")
    public Response getCustomMessage(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        String output = handler.greetUser(name);

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

}
```

I need a hook in the Handler.greetUser to be able to customize per client

```
package com.myapi.greetings.handler;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import com.myapi.greetings.dao.GreetingsDao;

public class DefaultGreetingsHandler implements GreetingsHandler {

    @Inject
    GreetingsDao dao;

    @Override
    public String greetUser(String name) {
        return dao.getGreeting() + name;
    }

}
```

Its a simple maven based rest project in java. Please refer to following link for the complete setup zip file.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AulFHVWnSJeFaqIB0JHKzo95DbU

Appreciate the help.

Comment: why is `DefaultGreetingsHandler` not a Rest method?

Comment: I suppose this is a meant to be a layered architecture, REST/business logic/DAO. That way concerns of the business logic can be separated from REST requests and marshalling request/response objects. I'm lost, though, on what your question is, @Sudhi.

Comment: @Sander Verhagen, what I am looking for is to be able to customize the base implementation of the greetUser (contains business logic), that will be client specific. The base implementation is my main product and has a default behavior, now at my different clients I should have ability to change the default behavior for their (client specific) custom implementations which will be in a different code base

Comment: So, you want different implementations of the `GreetingsHandler` interface?

Comment: Yes, I want a different implementation of GreetingsHandler which should be able to use the DefaultGreetingsHandler. I do inject my in my Service class and can have a named inject but is there any other way to do it without touching the original code? This is a product, so think of your original product and each customer/client can have a custom implementation on the existing product. Please refer to the link in my OP, it has a simple working project.

Answer (score 0):

Create a New Class MyApplicationBinder

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;

public class MyApplicationBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(GreetingsHandler.class).to(GreetingsHandler.class);
    }
}
```

and then Register it in the main application class

```
@ApplicationPath("webapi")
public class MyApp extends ResourceConfig{
    public MyApp() {
        register(new MyApplicationBinder());
        packages(true, "com.myapi.greetings.rest");
    }
}
```

This should make your application work  .

Comment: My Application works, what I am looking for is to be able to customize the base implementation of the greetUser (contains business logic), that will be client specific. The base implementation is my main product and has a default behavior, now at my different clients I should have ability to change the default behavior for their custom implementations which will be in a different code base.